# For a list of files how do I run a build script only for the files that were changed?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a list of files and want to run some program for every file, but only if it was changed. So I put all the files in the vector and iterated, like this:

```
// build.rs

let files = vec![
    "fileA",
    "fileB",
];

for file in files{
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed={}", file);

    let output = Command::new("glslangValidator")
        .args(&["-V", file, "-o", file])
        .output()
        .expect("failed to run glslangValidator");
}
```

This works, but the build process runs for **every** file even if only one from the list was changed. Instead, I want `glslangValidator` to be called **only** for the files that were changed between builds.

Comment: If the command you're calling produces an output file, a common technique would be to compare the modification date of the output file against the source file. You would only need to call the tool when the output file is older than the source file. Is there an actual output file here?

Comment: @SirDarius Yes, there's an output. And this is a good idea. I expected though there's something builtin in Rust,  but I can't find anything similar in the docs. Could you please add this as an answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Comment: Done, and I added an example that *should* compile based on something similar I did for https://github.com/noirotm/advent-of-code-2018/blob/master/build.rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the command you're calling produces an output file, a common technique would be to compare the modification date of the output file against the modification date of the source file.

You would only need to call the tool when the output file is older than the source file, or if the output file does not exist.

Example:

```
fn is_input_file_outdated<P1, P2>(input: P1, output: P2) -> io::Result<bool>
where
    P1: AsRef<Path>,
    P2: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let out_meta = fs::metadata(output);
    if let Ok(meta) = out_meta {
        let output_mtime = meta.modified()?;

        // if input file is more recent than our output, we are outdated
        let input_meta = fs::metadata(input)?;
        let input_mtime = input_meta.modified()?;

        Ok(input_mtime > output_mtime)
    } else {
        // output file not found, we are outdated
        Ok(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would note that since timestamp can be problematic -- for example, what if the input file is modified after you read it but before the output is produced? or the OS has issue? -- a slightly safer version is to produce a good hash of the input file _that you read_ (say, SHA-1 or SHA-2) and check _that_ against a reference.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed this is safer but it would require managing saved data, store it somewhere, read from the file, etc.